# ZF2 multiple tables join in one model, get columns from join table

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-framework2

So here is my query:

```
public function fetchAd($adID){
    $row = $this->tableGateway->select(function(Select $select) use ($adID){
        $select->join('adDetails','adDetails.adID = ads.adID',array('*'),'inner');
        $select->where(array('ads.adID' => $adID));
    });

    return $row->current();
}
```

So what I'm doing I'm querying the `ad` table and join the `adDetails` table in order for me to get the details for a certain AD, the problem is that the entity `AD` which belongs to the model that I'm doing the query, it doesn't have the columns names(variables) from the `adDetails` table; so it will only return the columns from the `AD` table, because the entity doesn't have those fields in the `exchangeArray()`

I have tried to extend the `AD` entity to use the `AdDetails` entity but it returns now to object array but with the fields as null, because it can;t populate them.

So, how should I do this, in order for me to have all the columns available in the model for the tables that will join?

I'm planning to join other tables as well.

Comment: I think relations between objects is not yet possible in ZF2, I guess I will have to copy manually all the vars from the entity and set them in the exchangeArray()

Answer (score 2):

Ok I solved the problem, the thing is that it will return an array, and it won't use the ORM style, but it does the job, for now relations are not supported in ZF2 like in ZF1;

```
    use Zend\Db\Sql\Sql,
        Zend\Db\Sql\Where;
    $sql = new Sql($this->tableGateway->getAdapter());
    $select = $sql->select();
    $select->from($this->tableGateway->table)
          ->join('adDetails','adDetails.adID = ads.adID',array('*'),'inner');

    $where = new  Where();
    $where->equalTo('ads.adID', $adID) ;
    $select->where($where);

    $statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
    $result = $statement->execute();

    return $result->current();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function fetchJoin() 
{ 
    $select = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Select; 
    $select->from('tablea a'); 
    $select->columns(array('*')); 
    $select->join('tableb b', "b.id = a.b_id", array('field1'), 'left'); 
    // to display query string remove comment in next line
    //echo $select->getSqlString(); 
    $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select); 
    return $resultSet; 
}
```